# JavaScript Regex finding all substrings that matches with specific starting and ending pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a Javascript regex or with any possible solution,
For a given string finds all the substrings that start with a particular string and end with a particular character. The returned set of subStrings can be an Array.

this string can also have nested within parenthesis.

```
var str = "myfunc(1,2) and myfunc(3,4) or (myfunc(5,6) and func(7,8))";
```

starting char = "myfunc" ending char = ")" . here ending character should be first matching closing paranthesis.

output: function with arguments.

```
[myfunc(1,2),
 myfunc(3,4),
 myfunc(5,6),
 func(7,8)]
```

I have tried with this. but, its returning null always.

```js
var str = "myfunc(1,2) and myfunc(3,4) or (myfunc(5,6) and func(7,8))";

var re = /\myfunc.*?\)/ig
var match;
while ((match = re.exec(str)) != null){
  console.log(match);
}
```

Can you help here?

Comment: Why are you escaping the `m`?

Comment: @Phil, I have used "myfunc" as starting string and expected to get as "myfunc(1,2)"

Comment: You literally have `\m` which AFAIK does nothing but it's an unnecessary escape sequence so I was asking _why?_

Comment: ok, Can you help how the regex should be , to get the expected result?

Comment: I made your code into a runnable snippet and it doesn't return `null` at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your regex and it seems to work fine:

```js
let input = "myfunc(1,2) and myfunc(3,4) or (myfunc(5,6) and func(7,8))"

let pattern = /myfunc.*?\)/ig 
// there is no need to use \m since it does nothing, and NO you dont need it even if you use 'm' at the beginning.

console.log(input.match(pattern)) 
//[ "myfunc(1,2)", "myfunc(3,4)", "myfunc(5,6)" ]
```

If you use `(?:my|)func\(.+?\)` you will be able to catch 'func(7,8)' too.

```
(?:my|)

(    start of group
?:   non capturing group
my|  matches either 'my' or null, this will match either myfunc or func
)    end of group
```

Test the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/3ujbdA/1

Comment: I think you mean `(my)?` for that last bit

Comment: @Phil nope, it is meant to be `(me|)`. I have added a link to test the regex, test it with and without the '|'.

Comment: Ah ok, pretty much the same thing but you don't see `|` with an empty right-hand-side in the wild very often